# How can I use a bot to create custom buttons?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, uiglassbutton

How can I use a bot to create custom buttons?

In the past, I used a few different bots to create glass buttons in telegram, but now they are inactive and none of them work.  Perhaps Telegram blocked the bots from accessing their API.

Suggestions are welcome.  I am familiar with telegram bots and if you have any function or source I can use it too (in PHP).

Comment: Updated the question to be more direct

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: So far, I've been using bots. But all of them fell off and I can't create any glass button with those bots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline keyboard buttons (glass buttons) are available now in telegram bot api.
You can see details at [inline keyboards](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup).